# Algolia numeric filter OR

Tags: logic, numeric, algolia

We are using Algolia for our search engine.
In one index we have an attribute : contract.monthDuration, which contains intergers.

I use the following numeric filter with success :

```
"contract.monthDuration:0 to 3"
```

But I am unable to use something like

```
"contract.monthDuration:0 to 3" OR "contract.monthDuration:4 to 6"
```

I have tried :

```
"contract.monthDuration:0 to 3 OR contract.monthDuration:4 to 6"
"contract.monthDuration:0 to 3,4 to 6"
"contract.monthDuration:0 to 3, contract.monthDuration:4 to 6"
"(contract.monthDuration:0 to 3, contract.monthDuration:4 to 6)"
```

Answer (score 5):

The correct syntax is

```
"(contract.monthDuration:0 to 3, contract.monthDuration:4 to 6)"
```

It actually works when using the JS API, but doesn't when one tests it directly in the algolia dashboard.